# Match all values in IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

here is my data:
T1

```
P.ID   UniqueID   Value    
 1      1       Apple    
 1      2       Orange    
 1      3       Grapes    
 2      4       Peach    
 2      5       Orange    
 2      6       Banana
```

T2 (lookup table)

```
Value
Apple
Orange
Grapes
Peach
Melon
Berry
```

I need categorize the data into 2 categories:

- if all records of each parent id in T1 have a match in T2, then Type1
- if any one of the records in T1 for the parent id does not have a
  match in T2, then Type2.

Currently, I am using an IN clause to query T2

```
select ID from T1 where T1.value in(select value from T2)
```

But I seem to be getting records that do not have a match in T2 as well using thie logic. how do I differentiate these? In my example above, ID 2 should be Type 2, and ID 1 is Type 1.

Comment: What does the required output look like? One row for each distinct `P_id`? (don't use dots in column names!) Or one row for each row in table `T1`?

Comment: Required output is only P_ids.

Comment: Also, I need 2 separate queries for both the types.

Comment: Why do you need two separate queries? It can all be done in a single query. How is the output (whether in one query or two) consumed (that is, processed further, or simply shown on reports)?

Comment: @mathguy We just need to queries for further processing to generate reports based on the 2 types. I tried left join but doesnt seem to help. If a P_id has atleast 1 row (like #2) that doesnt have a value in the lookup, then it shouldnt show up in my output for Type 2.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query:

```
select    T1.ID,
          case count(*) when count(T2.value) 
            then 'Type1'
            else 'Type2'
          end as Type 
from      T1 
left join T2 on T1.value = T2.value
group by  T1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need two queries anyway:

To get type 2:

```
select unique p_id from t1 where value not in (select value from t2)
```

Then save (store) the result in a temp table, or make this into a view. Either way, let's say you call it t3.

To get type 1:

```
select unique p_id from t1 where p_id not in (select p_id from t3)
```

Comment: this will not work, because P_id #2 has 2 other values that are in T2. so #2 will show up in Type 1 instead of Type 2.

Comment: @Skn - Do you think it will not work, or did you try? When you say "this" what are you referring to - the first query or the second? (I ask because you are wrong either way, but to tell you why, I need to know what you mean.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temp result that checks for each row separately if the value exists in the lookup table, and then select the `max` of these checks for each group. Thereby, if at least one row in a group has no reference (i.e. a `Type 2` for this row), then the `max` for the group is `Type 2`, too:

```
select id, max(type)
from 
  (select id, nvl(t2.value,'Type 2', 'Type 1') as type 
   from t1 left join t2 on t1.value = t2.value)
group by id
```